# Can a hash algorithm get identified by its result with any input?

Tags: hash

I want to identify hash algorithms without names (like sha256, ).

Is there a problem in make sha256('') and use the output like the id?

An empty string is really an empty input or this input is no really unique?

Thanks!

Comment: I kinda want to ask "why"?

Answer (score 2):

Identifying hash algorithms by the hash of the empty string works for all correct implementations of common hash algorithms. Every implementation that I ever met correctly handles the empty string. Sometime it's value is part of the hash specification.

```
MD5      d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
SHA      f96cea198ad1dd5617ac084a3d92c6107708c0ef
SHA-1    da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
SHA-256  e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

The technique would however fail to distinguish between two hash algorithms that differ only in their conversion of input to internal words, e.g. because of an endianness issue. An improvement from that standpoint would be $H(H(e))$ where $e$ is the empty string, and $H(e)$ is expressed as bytes before re-hashing. E.g:

```
MD5      59adb24ef3cdbe0297f05b395827453f
SHA      8cc209f1b453b098b81c2eab1a4fff022e8747a4
SHA-1    be1bdec0aa74b4dcb079943e70528096cca985f8
SHA-256  5df6e0e2761359d30a8275058e299fcc0381534545f55cf43e41983f5d4c9456
```

If we want to stick to a shorter and fixed bytestring which hash is widely available, the 3-bytes bytesring `616263` (`abc` per 8-bit ASCII or UTF-8) is a popular choice, being used in the spec of [MD5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1321#appendix-A.5), [SHA](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180.pdf#page=14), [SHA-1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/FIPS/fipspub180-1.pdf#page=18), [SHA-256](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/180/2/archive/2002-08-01/documents/fips180-2.pdf#page=40), and many other hashes.

```
MD5      900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
SHA      0164b8a914cd2a5e74c4f7ff082c4d97f1edf880
SHA-1    a9993e364706816aba3e25717850c26c9cd0d89d
SHA-256  ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad
```

Note: this first three algorithms in the lists are broken and should not be used in new applications, especially if collision-resistance is required.

Comment: I tried to [google 59adb24ef3cdbe0297f05b395827453f](https://www.google.com/search?q=59adb24ef3cdbe0297f05b395827453f) and can't explain some of the first hits.

Comment: NIST provides the empty string as test values...